# Which function(s) to build a paged HTML table

Tags: theme-development, ajax, html

are there built-in functions to build a modern HTML grid (as in grid control, not css grid layout) in WordPress? for example, one that is page-able and sortable.

Comment: This seems to me as a set of needs that is assorted enough that single plugin to handle it is unlikely, but not detailed enough to start suggesting specific plugins for separate list items. Could you please break it down into separate more detailed questions? Probably 1, 2+3 and 4.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the admin? Since 3.1, a new table API is available - check out the `WP_List_Table` class, and `WP_Posts_List_Table` as an example of how to use this.

Comment: this would be inside a wordpress Page

Answer (score 1):

There are no built-in functions to build grids, this is a design element, and you should use CSS frameworks.

- http://960.gs/
- http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssgrids/
- http://cssgrid.net/
- http://www.blueprintcss.org/

Modern HTML grids are built using DIV elements, styled in CSS.

Comment: poffle. If you want to display tabular data, you use a table.

Comment: He did not ask about tabular data. He asked about grids. Tabular data is not the same as grids. Modern layouts are built using grids. Tabular data assumes a database and lots of rows. You shouldn't have -1'd me.

Comment: "he" is me. I was referring to a "grid"-like control, as is common in GUI applications. I was not referring to a css grid layout. If you can point me to a pageable, sortable grid control that doesn't use HTML tables, I'd love to see it.

Comment: OK, I see what you mean. Your question was a bit ambiguous. Try searching for jQuery sorting tables.

Comment: If you want to sort a table ("table" as in "tabular data") that is, there is always the [TableSorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches to grid layouts and WordPress doesn't say which one you should use. So no, it is up to the theme developer to implement one.